# How to run an application in an interface?

Tags: java

I created a GUI-Interface

The interface display a button "run" and a "blanck space" for the user to enter his cods I want the button run to run the entered code by eclipse.

Is there a command that I should add to the button run?

Comment: So you want something like Inception?

Comment: If you created a GUI you will know what a compiler is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Save code in file.
2. Get it's absolute Path.
3. Use `Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` to
   compile and run your code.
4. You can also redirect Errors/Warnings to diff files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want. If you only want the user to be able to execute certain predefined commands then you just parse the content of the "blank space" which is probably an textedit field.

If you want the user to dynamically invoke methods then you'll need to use reflection. That's used like this:

The declaration

```
method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
```

The call

```
method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2,...);
```

Of course you need to import java.lang.reflect.Method method;

And take care of the thrown exceptions